# python HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using python 2.7, Ubuntu 14.04 and cv2. I'm trying to run this simple code:

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow("webcam", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I want to take a single picture, but instead my webcam stays activated but it only returns this:

```
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP
```

What I need to do to fix the problem?

Comment: I think you have compiled OpenCV without installing the development package for V4L.

Comment: How can I install the package for V4L then?

Answer (score 0):

Find your OpenCV directory in the the home folder and go there (something like the `cd` command I've written bellow, type your OpenCV directory there the code below is for my case!). Create a directory named `Release` and go inside the folder,

```
 cd /home/user/OpenCV
 mkdir Release
 cd Release
 sudo cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_GTK=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON ..
```

When running these commands on terminal please make sure you have permissions to those files or directories otherwise use `sudo` command to give them the access. After running the last one successfully type,

```
make
sudo make install
```